# remove script tag from ajax response data

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on a single page application using jQuery. whole html pages are sent as response to browser as ajax response.

```
$.post(url, function (data) {

  $("#resp").html(data);

  $("#resp").find("script").each(function (i) {
                //alert($(this).text());
                eval($(this).text());
  });
});
```

how to remove script tags from data and than assign html to the div ?

the issue i am facing is the scripts that are written in the response page. they were not getting added to the DOM at first, so i used eval(), now the scripts are getting added twice in some situations.

Comment: Maybe if you could post some relevant code to your issue we can help out a bit more

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function with a fragment selector, since that will strip out `<script>` tags prior to updating content and result in them not being executed. If you're working with entire HTML pages though there may not be a suitable selector for you to use. However, I'd suggest trying this first:

```
$('#resp').load(url + ' body');
```

That would give you just the content between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags in the HTML page requested via AJAX.

If that doesn't work, I guess you could try manually stripping out `<script>` tags from the response prior to adding to the DOM:

```
$.post(url, function(data) {
    var tempDiv = $('<div>').html(data).find('script').remove();
    $('#resp').html(tempDiv.html());
});
```

That creates a new `<div>` element that isn't part of the document, sets its HTML to the returned HTML from the AJAX request, searches for `<script>` elements inside that, and then removes them. However, even though the element isn't part of the current document yet, the scripts may still end up being executed (I've never had a reason to do this so I haven't tested it).

Comment: .remove() deletes all html except the script content. for eg if i return <div>some text</div><script>function aa(){ alert("hello")}</script> then it returns only function aa(){ alert("hello")}.

Answer (score 1):

with the help of Anthony's answer this is what i did to get it working :

```
$.post(url, function (data) {
    var tempDiv = $('<div>').html(data);
    var raw = $('<div>').html(data);
    $(tempDiv).find("script").remove();

    $("#resp").html(tempDiv.html());

    $(scripts).find("script").each(function (i) {
        //alert($(this).text());
        eval($(this).text());
    });
});
```

i could not understand why

```
var tempDiv = $('<div>').html(data).find('script').remove();
```

did'nt work though.